# Setting file contents with newlines and other special characters as environment variable with interpretation of included variables

Tags: environment-variables

Given I would like create environment variables from files containing newlines and special characters. The clue is that this content can have references to other environment variables which have to be intepreted. Maybe I need more complex tools than just plain bash?

A testfile "testfile.txt" could look like:

```
* foo
\/-!~ 
FOO=${FOOBAR}
```

What I have managed myself so far is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOOBAR="SUCCESS"
file="testfile.txt"
var_name="TEST"
name="$file"
content="$(<$file)"
echo "$content"
```

Which gives me a context variable as output (so, exactly the contents of the file):

```
* foo
\/-!~
FOO=${FOOBAR}
```

But, how can I:

1. Let ${FOOBAR} be set to "SUCCESS" as defined above but do not touch the rest?
2. Set an environment variable TEST  which would have content as (1)?

Comment: an additional aspect here whether it's possible to set the resulting multi-line substituted-values variable as environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on and adapted from the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683349/forcing-bash-to-expand-variables-in-a-string-loaded-from-a-file

```
#!/bin/bash
export FOOBAR="SUCCESS"
file="testfile.txt"
var_name="TEST"
name="$file"

content="$(envsubst < "$file")"
echo "$content"
```

Unlike `eval`, `envsubst` only substitutes variables, there is no risk of executing other programs via command substitution or similar.  It's a very simple templating tool for shell.

`envsubst` is part of the GNU gettext internationalisation utilities (on debian, it's in the `gettext-base` package).

Note that `envsubst` (being an external command, not a shell built-in) can only see variables that have been exported (but see the `allexport` standard `sh` option to make the shell export subsequently defined variables to the environment).

Comment: Note that only `$X` and `${X}` are supported. Not `${X#pattern}` (even if you have a `X#pattern` environment variable), `${X-default}`... And there's no escaping `\$VAR` becomes `\content-of-$VAR`. `$$VAR` becomes `$content-of-$VAR`... Probably what the OP wants in the first place but worth pointing out.

Comment: yep, it's very limited and very simple.  simple variable substitutions only, a very primitive templating tool.  also reasonably safe.  and, in addition to the problems you mentioned, if the template file contains $FOOBAR but that variable doesn't exist or isn't exported then it gets replaced with the empty string...this can be a feature OR a bug depending on what you want.  It can even be both a feature and a bug in the same template file :).   Conclusion: **For anything but the most basic templating, use awk or perl or python or anything-but-shell.**

Comment: but, how can I expose the result as environment variable?

Comment: you can capture the output of anything that prints to stdout with, e.g.,  `content="$(....)"`.  same as I used for `envsubst` above.   Note that almost all languages have some form of easy access to exported environment variables - e.g. perl has a hashed array `%ENV` that contains the environment, so you'd access the export FOOBAR shell var with `$ENV{FOOBAR}`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
eval "content=\$(cat << @@@EOF@@@
$(cat file)
@@@EOF@@@
)"
```

That will expand the parameter, arithmetic and command substitutions, and `\` is used for escaping (of `$`, `` ` `` and itself only) and line-continuation. For instance, on an input like:

```
* foo
\/-!~ 
FOO=${FOOBAR} $((1+1)) $(uname)
\${FOOBAR}\\foo\
bar
```

That gives something like:

```
* foo
\/-!~
FOO=content-of-$FOOBAR 2 Linux
${FOOBAR}\foobar
```

It should be obvious that it's a command injection vulnerability if the content of the file is not under your full control.